# Update a table in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure that has parameters. If I pass the parameter, the query is to update the table by the `LocationID`.

The stored procedure is as follows:

```
CREATE proc [Location].[SPUpadtelocation_by_locationID]
    @Name       nvarchar(100),
    @Parentcode nvarchar(10),
    @CLientcode nvarchar(10),
    @Address    nvarchar(100),
    @city       nvarchar(20),
    @state      nvarchar(20),
    @Pin        int,
    @Clientid   int,
    @Status     bit,
    @Fax        int,
    @CreatedAt  date,
    @AccessAt   datetime,
    @Accessby   int,
    @LocationID int 
as
begin 
     if (select LocationID 
         from Location.tbl_Locationmaster 
         where Parentcode = @Parentcode 
           and Clientcode = @Clientcode  
           and Clientid = @Clientid) = @LocationID --check Location allready exists or not 
     begin 
         UPDATE [Location].[tbl_Locationmaster]
         SET [Name] = @Name,
             [Parentcode] = @Parentcode,
             [Clientcode] = @CLientcode,
             [Address] = @Address,
             [City] = @city,
             [State] = @state, 
             [Pin] = @Pin,
             [Clientid] = @Clientid, 
             [Status] = @Status,
             [Fax] = @Fax,
             [AccessAt] = getdate(),
             [Accessby] = @Accessby
         WHERE 
             LocationID = @LocationID
     end
end
GO
```

I don't want to update the `Name` column, `ParentCode` column and `ClientCode` column of `Location` table if the `Parentcode` and the `Clientcode` are already in the table for same `Client`. But the rest of the column should be updated.

Comment: If you don't want update `Name`, `ParentCode` and `ClientCode` in your `tbl_Locationmaster` table then no need to add into update query. Just remove from update query.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) and the [CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) statements on MSDN.  They both provide examples for doing conditional UPDATEs to specific columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one entry per client then your `IF` logic should be like below

```
if (select LocationID from Location.tbl_Locationmaster where Parentcode=@Parentcode and Clientcode =@Clientcode  and Clientid=@Clientid) = @LocationID --check Location already exists or not 
begin 
    UPDATE [Location].[tbl_Locationmaster]
        SET
            [Name] = COALESCE([Name],@Name)
            ,[Parentcode] =COALESCE([Parentcode],@Parentcode)
            ,[Clientcode] = COALESCE([Clientcode],@CLientcode)
            ,[Address] = @Address
            ,[City] = @city
            ,[State] = @state
            ,[Pin] = @Pin
            ,[Clientid] = @Clientid
            ,[Status] = @Status
            ,[Fax] = @Fax
            ,[AccessAt] = getdate()
            ,[Accessby] = @Accessby
    WHERE LocationID = @LocationID
end
```

In case you have multiple location rows for same `client ID` and you do not want the update the current location row in such case  with new data your logic should be like

```
if (select LocationID from Location.tbl_Locationmaster where Parentcode=@Parentcode and Clientcode =@Clientcode  and Clientid=@Clientid) = @LocationID --check Location already exists or not 
begin 
    UPDATE L
        SET
            [Name] = CASE T.[Name] IS NOT NULL THEN L.[NAME] ELSE @Name END
            ,[Parentcode] =CASE T.[Parentcode] IS NOT NULL THEN L.[ParentCode] ELSE @Parentcode END
            ,[Clientcode] = CASE T.[Clientcode] IS NOT NULL THEN L.[Clientcode] ELDE @CLientcode END
            ,[Address] = @Address
            ,[City] = @city
            ,[State] = @state
            ,[Pin] = @Pin
            ,[Clientid] = @Clientid
            ,[Status] = @Status
            ,[Fax] = @Fax
            ,[AccessAt] = getdate()
            ,[Accessby] = @Accessby
    FROM [Location].[tbl_Locationmaster] L
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT Name, ParentCode,ClientCode FROM [Location].[tbl_Locationmaster] ) T
ON T.[Clientid] = @Clientid 
WHERE L.LocationID = @LocationID 
end
```